# $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{(y^2-x)^2}{y^4+x^2}$ does not exist at $(0,0)$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Why does

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{(y^2-x)^2}{y^4+x^2}$$

not have a limit at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Use polar coordinates, it's easy.

Comment: Try different ways of tending to $(0,0)$, and see it has different values depending on the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $y^2=x$ we have the limit becomes $0$.

Let $y^2=2x$ we have the limit becomes $x^2\over 5x^2$$={1\over5}$.

Hence it cannot exist.